# How do I property roll up and/or combinations in NEST?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, filter, boolean-logic, nest

## Background

### What I'm Trying to Do

- I have a list of vehicles.
- I have an API (WebAPI v2) that takes in a list of filters for a make and models

  - a filter consists of 1 make and 0 or more models. (e.g. "Honda" and ["Civic", "Accord"])
- If a filter is passed in with a make and no models, I want it to match all models for that make.
- If a filter is passed in with a make and models, I want it to make only those models for that make.

#### The Filter Object I'm using

```
public class MakeModelFilter : IMakeModelFilter
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public List<string> Models { get; set; }
}
```

#### What the entire API Call Looks Like

```
{
    "MakeModelFilters": [
        {"Make": "BMW", "Models": ["X3", "X5"]}
    ],
    "TypeFilter": [],
    "GenericColorFilter": [],
    "FeaturesFilter": [],
    "MaxMileage" : 100000,
    "PriceRange": {"Min": 1, "Max": 1000000},
    "SearchText": ""
}
```

The portion I'm concerned with is the MakeAndModelFilters list (the rest works as designed currently).

#### How I'm currently obtaining search results:

```
var vehicles = _esClient.Search<Vehicle>(s => s
    .From(0).Size(10000) 
    .Query(q => q
        .Filtered(fq => fq
            .Filter(ff => ff
                .Bool(b => b
                    .Must(m=> m.And(
                                m.Or(makeModelFilterList.ToArray()),
                                m.Or(featureFilters.ToArray()), 
                                m.Or(typeFilters.ToArray()),
                                priceRangeFilter, 
                                mileageFilter))
                )
            )
            .Query(qq => qq
                .QueryString(qs => qs.Query(criteria.SearchText))
            )
        )
    )
);
```

## The Problem

No matter how I structure the filter, it seems to filter out all documents -- not in our best interest. :) Something in my boolean logic is wrong.

#### Where I think the problem lies

The list of make and model filters that I `or` together is generated by this method:

```
private List<FilterContainer> GenerateMakeModelFilter(List<MakeModelFilter> makeModelFilters)
{
    var filterList = new List<FilterContainer>();
    foreach (var filter in makeModelFilters)
    {
        filterList.Add(GenerateMakeModelFilter(filter));
    }

    return filterList;
}
```

This method calls the individual method to generate a bool for each make/model filter I have.

#### What I think the problem method is

The below method, as far as I'm aware, does the following:

- If no make is passed in, throw exception
- If only a make is passed in, return a bool for only that make.
- If a make and models are passed in, return an a bool of the make filter + an `or` of all the model terms. e.g. `Make:BMW AND (model:X3 OR model:X5)`

Code is below:

```
private FilterContainer GenerateMakeModelFilter(MakeModelFilter makeModelFilter)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(makeModelFilter.Make)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(makeModelFilter));}

    var makeFilter = new TermFilter { Field = Property.Path<Vehicle>(it => it.Make), Value = makeModelFilter.Make };
    var boolMake = new BoolFilter { Must = new List<FilterContainer> { makeFilter } };

    var modelFilters = GenerateFilterList(Property.Path<Vehicle>(it => it.Model), makeModelFilter.Models);

    if (!modelFilters.Any())
    {
        // If it has a make but no model, generate boolFilter make only.
        return boolMake;
    }

    var orModels = new OrFilter {Filters = modelFilters};
    var boolModels = new BoolFilter {Must = new List<FilterContainer> {orModels}};

    var boolMakeAndModels = new AndFilter {Filters = new List<FilterContainer> {boolMake, boolModels}};

    return new BoolFilter {Must = new List<FilterContainer> {boolMakeAndModels}};
}
```

FYI, `GenerateFilterList` just creates a list of Term filters and returns the list.

### FYI: Generated ElasticSearch JSON

This might be a clue to where I'm going wrong (though it's huge). I've just been staring at it so long that I can't see it I think.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "and": {
                "filters": [
                  {
                    "or": {
                      "filters": [
                        {
                          "bool": {
                            "must": [
                              {
                                "and": {
                                  "filters": [
                                    {
                                      "bool": {
                                        "must": [
                                          {
                                            "term": {
                                              "make": "BMW"
                                            }
                                          }

                                        ]
                                      }
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "bool": {
                                        "must": [
                                          {
                                            "or": {
                                              "filters": [
                                                {
                                                  "term": {
                                                    "model": "x3"
                                                  }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                  "term": {
                                                    "model": "x5"
                                                  }
                                                }

                                              ]
                                            }
                                          }
                                        ]
                                      }
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  { },
                  { },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "sellingPriceUSD": {
                        "lte": "1000000",
                        "gte": "1"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "miles": {
                        "lte": "100000"

                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Refactor 1: Move more Towards Bitwise operations

Per Martijn's answer and [Zachary's post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets) that he references, I've updated my `GenerateFilterList` to return a concatenated filterContainer:

```
private FilterContainer GenerateFilterList(PropertyPathMarker path, List<string> filter)
{
    if (filter == null || filter.Count <= 0){ return null; }

    FilterContainer returnFilter = null;
    foreach (var aFilter in filter)
    {
        returnFilter |= new TermFilter {Field = path, Value = aFilter.ToLowerInvariant()};
    }

    return returnFilter;
}
```

And then for my `GenerateMakeModelFilter`, I perform an "and" against the "model filters", which should be a bitwise or based on the above code:

```
private FilterContainer GenerateMakeModelFilter(MakeModelFilter makeModelFilter)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(makeModelFilter.Make)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(makeModelFilter)); }

    var makeFilter = new TermFilter { Field = Property.Path<Vehicle>(it => it.Make), Value = makeModelFilter.Make };

    var modelFilters = GenerateFilterList(Property.Path<Vehicle>(it => it.Model), makeModelFilter.Models);

    return makeFilter && modelFilters;
}
```

This shortens the part that retrieves the query:

```
QueryContainer textQuery = new QueryStringQuery() {Query = criteria.SearchText };
FilterContainer boolFilter = makeModelFilter || featureFilter || typeFilter || priceRangeFilter || mileageFilter;

var vehicles = _esClient.Search<Vehicle>(s => s
.From(0).Size(10000) //TODO: Extract this into a constant or setting in case the inventory grows to 10k+. This prevents it from paging.
.Query(q => q
    .Filtered(fq => fq
        .Filter(filter => filter.Bool(bf => bf.Must(boolFilter)))
        .Query(qq => textQuery)
        )
    )   
);

return vehicles.Documents.ToList<IVehicle>();
```

**...but I still have no documents returned**. What the heck am I missing? If I have a Make of Honda with Models of "Civic" and "Accord", and a make of "BMW" with no models, I should receive all vehicles with honda + civic || honda + accord || bmw + (any model). I'll keep at it.

Comment: Also, PS: if I take the make/model combination out and just to an `or` on the models, it works as intended. So I think it has to be something in the bool roll-up between makes and models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And,or, & not filters might not be doing what you want. They are a special filter construct that performs better when combining filters that do not operate on bitsets. Must read on this topic:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets

Knowing when to use and/or/not filters vs bool filters can be quite confusing and with Elasticsearch 2.0 you can use the bool filter in ALL contexts and it will know how to best execute the filters/queries in its clauses. No more need for you to hint!

Further more although the bool filter/query is named bool it does a unary bool whereas you might expect it to be a binary bool.

This is why the bool clauses are must/should/must_not vs and/or/not.

In NEST if you use the `&&` `||` `!` operators combined with parenthesis we will compose one or many bool queries so that it acts in the binary bool fashion you write it down in C#.

e.g:

```
.Query(q=>q
    (q.Term("language", "php")
        && !q.Term("name", "Elastica")
    )
    ||
    q.Term("name", "NEST")
)
```

If you need a more dynamic list you can use the assignment operators `!=` and `&=`:

```
private FilterContainer GenerateMakeModelFilter(List<MakeModelFilter> makeModelFilters)
{
    FilterContainer filter = null;
    foreach (var filter in makeModelFilters)
    {
        filter |= GenerateMakeModelFilter(filter);
    }

    return filter;
}
```

Similarly if you refactor `GenerateMakeModelFilter` to take advantage of the C# boolean operator overloads you'll end up with an easier to read and debug query. Both in terms of C# as well as the query that gets send to Elasticsearch.

Our documentation goes into it in some more detail http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/writing-queries.html

**UPDATE**

Awesome refactor! Now we can focus on mappings in elasticsearch. When you index a json property it goes through [an analysis chain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) which takes the single string and tries to make 1 or more terms out of it that are going to be stored in lucene's inverted index.

By default elasticsearch will analyze all string fields using the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html)

In your case `BMW` will go through the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) which splits on whitespace ([Unicode standard annex #29 to be exact](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/)) and lowercases it.

So the term in the inverted index is `bmw`. In elasticsearch some queries are also analyzed at query time so a e.g [a match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) for `BMW` is also analyzed and transformed to `bmw` before consulting the inverted index and thus will find documents no matter the casing of `BMW` at query time.

The term query/filter that you are using is **not** analyzed at query time so it will try to find `BMW` in the inverted index where the inverted index only has `bmw`. This is great if you only want exact term matches. If you set up [your mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html) so that a field is not analyzed you could for instance do exact matches on `New York` without worrying its actually stored as two separate terms `new` and `york` and inadvertently also get results from [New New York](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/42/Futurama_-_The_Future.jpg)

Comment: thanks for jumping in! Zachary's blog post about bitsets that you reference has a large disclaimer saying it is no longer recommended advice. Should I not worry about that?

Comment: After reviewing the blog post, I've added update 1 to the question with refactoring towards your solution. However, I still seem to be returning no documents. Any further insight would be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure why it's not clicking. Thanks!

Comment: added an update to my answer as well. Zach's blog post no longer holds up for 2.0 (tried to explain that in the 2nd paragraph :)) but is still valid for 1.x. You are not using any filters that benefit from and/or/not though so just use the bool filter.

Comment: ahh shoot! I actually was aware of this; I missed it on the make filter but adjusted it correctly in my method that generates the list. Thank you! I'll fix that and hopefully then I can mark this as correct. Really appreciate it.